# Vertical align items in UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitoolbar

I'm adding a `UIToolbar` to the bottom of my `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UIEdgeInsets safeInsets = self.view.safeAreaInsets;
    self.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-(49.0f+safeInsets.bottom), self.view.frame.size.width, (49.0f+safeInsets.bottom));
}
```

This gives the `UIToolbar` the correct height. However, what happens on iPhone X is that the items are vertically centered in the toolbar, resulting in a pretty weird look.

Is there any way to move them to the top? Or should I use the safe area of the iPhone X in a different way?

Comment: Can you show me how it looks on iPhone X?